# Value cannot be null. Error

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have an error with the method below where I am trying to add data from a `combobox` to a `datagrid` and then after I add the data I want to calculate the total amount of the 'ItemSellingPrice' and display that amount in a label.

```
using (TruckServiceClient TSC = new TruckServiceClient())
{
    var item = cmbAddExtras.SelectedItem as ExtraDisplayItems;

    if (item != null)
    {
        var displayItem = new List<ExtraDisplayItems>
        {
            new ExtraDisplayItems 
            { 
                displayItems = item.displayItems,
                ItemId = item.ItemId, 
                ItemCode = item.ItemCode, 
                ItemDescription = item.ItemDescription, 
                ItemSellingPrice = item.ItemSellingPrice,
            }
        };
        dgAddExtras.Items.Add(item);
        var subTotalExtras = item.displayItems.Sum(x => x.ItemSellingPrice.GetValueOrDefault(0)); //Here
        lblSubTotalExtrasAmount.Content = "R" + subTotalExtras;
    }
}
```

The error that I get is:

> Value cannot be null.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT:** This is where I set the displayItems in my class

```
public class ExtraDisplayItems
{
    public List<ExtraDisplayItems> displayItems;

    public int ItemId { get; set; }    
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }    
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }    
    public double? ItemSellingPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold), the actual issue is that the `item.displayItems` is `null` (so not inside the lambda, since that works perfectly fine).

Some proof. This gets your exact error message:

```
double?[] x = null;
double? sum = x.Sum(y => y);
```

(The reason you don't get a `NullReferenceException` is that you actually call a static method (an extension method), so technically the reference isn't null but the argument is).

You should check where you set `item.displayItems` or prevent calling `Sum` on a `item.displayItems` with value `null`.

Comment: Hi again Patrick ;). This was not the answer though. I am still getting the same error?

Comment: No, *Value cannot be null.* is the message you get when the first parameter of a LINQ extension method is null, `item.displayItems` in this case.

Comment: This is wrong. [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs.html#3f64ed9c588d83c4) simply silently skips over null values.

Comment: @GertArnold Indeed. Thanks for commenting. Fixed the answer.

Comment: @hvd indeed. Just like Gert already pointed out Fixed it now.

Comment: Yeah, four seconds before I did, so that didn't give me the time to see his comment before adding my own. :) Your answer looks good to me now.